# "ng new" option - angular-cli

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular-cli

After installing,

```
$ node -v
v6.11.5
$ npm -v
3.10.10
$ ng --version
0.7.0
$ which ng
/usr/bin/ng
$ ng

  Usage: ng <command> [options]


  Options:

    -V, --version  output the version number
    -h, --help     output usage information


  Commands:

    init              Alias for "yo ng-factory"
    build             Alias for "gulp ng:build"
    serve [options]   Alias for "gulp ng:serve"
```

---

`ng` does not give `new` option to run below command,

```
$ ng new angular-project
```

---

Is this the right install of `ng` package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so.  There current version of the `angular-cli` is `1.5.0` ([source](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases)).  You need to reinstall:

```
npm -g uninstall @angular/cli
npm -g install @angular/cli
```